# Architecture for Combined Desktop and Mobile Website?

Tags: model-view-controller, mobile, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I want to build a web site that will work for both mobile devices (i.e. smartphones and tablets) as well as desktop browsers. Is the current "best practice" for architecting such a site to use MVC and then create separate views and controllers for each "silo" (i.e. one set of views and controllers for desktop, another for phones, and a third for tablets (while hopefully sharing models)) and then use "responsive" design techniques within each silo to render the viewport correctly for each device (e.g. iPhone vs. Android, iPad vs. Fire)?

What options are there for architecting such a site?  Can you recommend any good articles that discuss this topic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll find one official answer, but here are a couple strategies that I've used:

- Use a [Responsive Theme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsiveness) - one site, scales to the browsers size. This solution is closely related to adaptive theming and may involve using media queries to load the proper css for the clients browser.
- Have two solutions, one for desktop and one for mobile (with a service layer doing most of the business logic)

Helpful articles?  For me, these helped:

- http://www.propublica.org/nerds/item/adaptive-design-fixed-widths-and-tablets - good intro
- http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/responsive-design-overview/ - includes some nice examples